# Drupal: Creating a view that retrieves related nodes based on terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to wrap my head around getting nodes that share the same taxonomy terms, but I have some questions.

Essentially, I want to display a view at the bottom of my event node that shows related events. I have tags for each event and will be using those to create the match.

In views, when I create a taxonomy argument and add multiple "tags" it searches for nodes with all the specified arguments. What I want is not to search just for nodes that contain all of the arguments, but nodes that contain either or. So far I haven't figured any solutions.

Edit:

Would it be easier to create a simple block module that queries the database for nodes that contain the terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a Taxonomy Term ID as argument and then I selected the checkbox that allows Multiple Terms per argument. Notice the help text that says, "If selected, users can enter multiple arguments in the form of 1+2+3 (for OR) or 1,2,3 (for AND)." By using the + sign you will OR the arguments together, but if you use the , then they will be AND together thus forcing nodes to have all terms. For this specific view I am providing the default argument via php and I am using the plus sign to wrap the term ID arguments together. This will give me all the nodes that are tagged with any of the terms supplied as arguments.

edit: I might want to also add that I have the checkbox selected for "Let Multiple arguments work together." That may or may not be needed for your use case, but I needed it for mine.